# Read Uncommitted in DB2--case sensitive?

Tags: db2

Is adding "with UR" in the DB2 query case sensitive?
for Example: "with UR" is it valid? or should it be "WITH UR" or "with ur"

Thanks.

Comment: Not a DB2 person, but in almost all RDBMS, the reserve keywords are case insensitive. Why not try all 3 locally and test ?

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are case-insensitive per SQL standard and also implemented in DB2. Thus, you can use `WITH UR`, `With Ur`, `WiTh uR` and several other permutations. Try it and have fun with SQL.